# AM I using DO WHILE NOT and EOF in VBscript Properly

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, vbscript

Finally the administrator configured the IIS for me the error message is listed below.
    Set SQLStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Set SQLConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set SQLCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        Set SQLRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        SQLConnection.Open "Provider=sqloledb;SERVER=SQLPROD;DATABASE=MyDataBase;UID=MyUsername;PWDMyPassword;"

```
    'Response.Write("Connection Status: " & SQLConnection.State) & vbnewline
    'Response.Write("Connection Provider: " & SQLConnection.Provider) & vbnewline
    'Response.Write("Version: " & SQLConnection.Version) & vbnewline

    SQLCommand.ActiveConnection = SQLConnection
    SQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Seminars.Year, Seminars.SeminarID, Seminars.Theme, Seminar_Week.First, Seminar_Week.Last, Seminar_Week.WeekID, Seminar_Week.Date, Seminar_Week.Affiliation FROM Seminars CROSS JOIN Seminar_Week"
    'Response.Write("SQL Command Passed in: " & SQLCommand.CommandText)

    Set adoRec = SQLCommand.Execute()
        file1 = "./seminars/" & seminar_type & "/" & seminar_year & "/" & adoRec("Date") & "-" & adoRec("Year") & "_" & adoRec("Last") & ".pdf"
        file2 = "./seminars/" & seminar_type & "/" & seminar_year & "/" & adoRec("Date") & "-" & seminar_year & "_" & adoRec("Last") & "(handouts).pdf"
        file3 = "./seminars/" & seminar_type & "/" & seminar_year & "/" & adoRec("Date") & "-" & seminar_year & "_" & adoRec("Last") & "_Flyer.pdf"
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        Response.Write("<p style=" & "margin-left:10px;" & "><img src=" & "./img/right_arrowblue.png" & " alt=" & "Expand/Collapse" & " id=" & "arrow_" & adoRec("Week") & " /><strong>[" & adoRec("Date") & "]</strong> " & "<a href=" & "javascript:toggle('seminar_" & adoRec("Week") &"')"">"&aroRec("First") & adoRec("Last") & ", " & adoRec("Affiliation") & "</a></p>")
```

The very last line of code causes this error

ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'

Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

*FilePath*, line 244

Line 244 is the very last line of code that should write Some information about each seminar on the webpage.

I'm pretty sure at this point I am pointing to an incorrect file path because I have an extra space somewhere in all the different string.

My question now is Would the ones in the very beginning, meaning the ones used in

```
"<p style=" & "margin-left:10px;" & "><img src=" & "./img/right_arrowblue.png"
```

be causing the trouble.

I'm also unfamiliar with using the "Expand/collapse" so if someone could tell me a little more about that. I am trying to fix someone elses code so I am a little behind the 8 ball.

Comment: If that is intended as VBScript, not using "Set" when assigning the return value of .Execute() is a fatal error; if the code is intended as VB.NET, then *please* correct the tags.

Comment: The Set in front of the .Execute() was causing an error on the page so I removed it and things started to work correctly again. Should I add it back in? If I do add it back in and start receiving an error again what would cause that?

Comment: Assuming you code in VBScript, the Set is necessary to get a recordset from .Execute(). If using Set causes errors, publish them. Do you have an "On Error Resume Next" active? Is yes, disable it, and publish error(s). If you are *not* using VBScript, all bets are off.

Comment: Yes this is VBscript. Perhaps I'm doing the record set wrong I've now added it to the code above so you can see that as well, There is no "on error resume next" and how would I implement publish errors? Sorry I am very new to VBscript

Comment: first, if possible, in IIS set so you get the actual errors. That'll give you a better idea what is the error and in what line it's happening.  Second, you need to specify a connection string for the connection. Third, you need to open the connection before the `.execute`

Comment: Sorry Should Have included all that in the code above. I now have everything I have so far in my VBscript posted above.

Comment: Also I do not have access to the IIS settings

Comment: If you want review your code then use http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you 4M01 I was unaware of this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small step to a solution:

Your SQL

```
"SELECT * FROM Seminars WHERE [SeminarID] = 5 ORDER BY DESC"
```

is definitely wrong: ORDER BY needs (at least) a column name: ORDER BY [SeminarID] DESC.

If that does not solve all your problems, we'll have to think about a step by step approach.

If you get errors, tell us about them (number, description, line). That's what I meant, when I ask you to publish them. If you can't better info than "There was an error when processing the URL" from IIS, then you **have** to write some command line script to get the database related code absolutely right.

Start with experiments.vbs:

```
  Dim sCS : sCS     = !your connection string!
  Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  oCN.Open sCS
  WScript.Echo "CN open:", oCN.State

  Dim sSQL : sSQL    = !your SQL statement!
  Dim oRS  : Set oRS = oCN.Execute(sSQL)
  WScript.Echo "RS EOF:", CStr(oRS.EOF)
  WScript.Echo "Frs Col:", oRS.Fields(0).Name, oRS.Fields(0).Type

  Dim i : i = 0
  Do Until oRS.EOF
     WScript.Echo i, oRS.Fields(0).Value
     i = i + 1
     oRS.MoveNext
  Loop
  oCN.Close
```

and run it in a command window (DOS box): cscript experiments.vbs. This should get you either some lines like:

```
CN open: 1
RS EOF: False
Frs Col: Id 3
0 ...
1 ...
2 ...
```

or a focused/publishable error message like:

```
... .vbs(2465, 14) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Falsche Syntax in der Nä
he des 'DESC'-Schlüsselworts.
```

(bad syntax near DESC), which got when I tried the statement

```
"SELECT * FROM Alpha ORDER BY DESC"
```

Comment: I added the column name to ORDER BY but I still receive errors.

Comment: CN open: 1 RS EOF: False, Frs Col: Year 3, 0 2011, 1 2010, 2 2011, ..., 6 null. THat read the database correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
RS.MoveNext
```

Put the above code on the line before the Loop keyword to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: Inserted the code but still receiving errors. Now says "There was an error when processing the URL" Any thoughts. Thanks for the above fix though infinite loops are never good

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the `loop` keyword at the end of your loop block?

Check the syntax here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx

Comment: the loop key word is there. I have edited the post to include it now.